# Mobile menu do not collapse on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

The menu is working fine on desktop using `hover` property. But the same is not closing using on-click on mobile and tabs.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-2 sec-menu-button mobile-vw navbar-brand">
                    <a href="browse-journals.php" class="btn button-ryt">Browse Journals</a>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-7"
                     aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-7" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-7">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="dropdown active">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="nav-label">RESOURCES</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/guide-for-editors.php">GUIDE FOR EDITIORS</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/guide-for-reviewers.php">GUIDE FOR REVIEWERS</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/guide-for-editor-in-chief.php">GUIDE FOR EDITION IN CHIEF</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="nav-label">AUTHORS GUIDE</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/editorial-work-flow.php">EDITIORIALS WORK FLOW</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="nav-label">EDITORIAL AND PUBLISHING POLICIES</span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/submission-policies.php">SUBMISSION POLICIES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/transfers.php">TRANSFERS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/license-agreement-and-author-copyright.php">LICENSE AGREEMENT AND AUTHORS COPYRIGHT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">USE OF EXPERIMENTAL ANIMAL &amp; HUMAN SUBJECTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">COMPETING INTERESTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DIGITAL IMAGES INTEGRITY AND STANDARDS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BIOSECURITY CONCERNS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DUPLICATE PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONFIDENTIALITY , PRE-PUBLICTY AND PREPRINTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PLAGIARISM AND FABRICATION</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/publication-fees.php">PUBLICATION FEES</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/article-preparation-instructions.php">ARTICLE PREPARATIONS INSTRUCTIONS</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/peer-review.php">PEER REVIEW</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/article-types.php">ARTICLE TYPES</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/open-access.php">OPEN ACCESS</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/publication-ethics.php">PUBLICATIONS ETHICS</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://amitpandey.tech/EmresOnline/faqs.php">FAQS</a></li>
    </ul>
                    
        <div class="col-md-2 sec-menu-button desktop-vw">
            <a href="browse-journals.php" class="btn button-ryt">Browse Journals</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am aware that these kind of questions has already been answered. But, I tried using them and got no luck. Please look into the issue and help me out.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/uf3kwsg. Can you be more specific about what's not working?

Comment: JS Fiddle link isn't working. Can you please check it.

Comment: Navbar working fine on desktop view, but its not closing menu drop-down in mobile devices.